bigrquery::bq_auth() fails with invalid_grant Bad Request warning in R
In a fresh R Session, bigrquery::bq_auth() fails when run locally / interactively with the following error, instead of sending me to the browser for authentication:
Warning message:
Unable to refresh token: invalid_grant
Bad Request

This is from an entirely fresh install of R / Rstudio and bigrquery -- bq_auth() was the third command run, after install.packages("tidyverse") and install.packages("bigrquery") (both done in a clean R session).
gargle::token_fetch() correctly sends me to the browser for a new authentication process and googledrive::drive_auth() also correctly authenticates, which tells me (a) the tidyverse API doesn't seem to be the problem and (b) Oauth / a bad token doesn't actually seem to be the problem either (lots of info on that in this thread). This points me more towards it being an issue with the bigrquery API / wrapper.
Does anyone have any ideas for what could be happening?
I wish I had a true reprex (welcome on any ideas here for kind of error!), but in the absence of that, here's my R sessionInfo():
R version 4.4.1 (2024-06-14)
Platform: aarch64-apple-darwin20
Running under: macOS Sonoma 14.5

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib 
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.4-arm64/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib;  LAPACK version 3.12.0

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

time zone: America/New_York
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[7] base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] utf8_1.2.4        R6_2.5.1          bit_4.0.5        
 [4] magrittr_2.0.3    rappdirs_0.3.3    glue_1.7.0       
 [7] tibble_3.2.1      pkgconfig_2.0.3   bit64_4.0.5      
[10] lifecycle_1.0.4   cli_3.6.3         bigrquery_1.5.1  
[13] askpass_1.2.0     fansi_1.0.6       openssl_2.2.0    
[16] gargle_1.5.2      vctrs_0.6.5       DBI_1.2.3        
[19] compiler_4.4.1    httr_1.4.7        rstudioapi_0.16.0
[22] tools_4.4.1       curl_5.2.1        pillar_1.9.0     
[25] rlang_1.1.4       jsonlite_1.8.8    fs_1.6.4         

